# Get current location using wifi?

Tags: android, android-wifi

How can i get current location using WiFi?
In my project using gps I can get current location ...
How can I use network service in android?

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener currentlocation = new CurrentLocation();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                currentlocation);
```

But I want current location WiFi?
Can anyone help me for getting current location using WiFi?

Comment: @Nanne what if i dont have 1....besides wifi is lot better can be controlled

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [NETWORK_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER).

Please note, that you will have to amend your AndroidManifest.xml as well by adding:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION implies ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION. There is no need to add both.